# How to fix "Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint." on linux with published app

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm trying to run a self-contained published linux-x64 .net 5.0 app on ubuntu, and i'm getting this error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
```

I don't have the `dotnet` command, since I don't have the SDK installed on the machine it's running on, that message is unhelpful (as are all the other SO answers I have seen regarding this error).

This message is new, the app was working fine before, but it just started happening. How do I make it work again?

Answer (score 0):

### Root Cause

The source code related to the exception can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/dbd904451c3ae1bae8cdc8905981fe6028333024/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.cs#L174)

The exception happens when ASP.NET Core cannot resolve a default certificate to use for HTTPS connections, and that's why the exception message tells you how to configure a default certificate. Like you described, that doesn't help much as this machine does not have .NET Core SDK installed.

### Solution

There are several options to go, and I suggest you switch to [the loading method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/dbd904451c3ae1bae8cdc8905981fe6028333024/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.cs#L38) that allow you to specify a certificate file. Microsoft has several articles on this topic, like [this one](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/).

Comment: right, but why did this code work fine before on this same machine, and what has caused it to start failing? i didn't have to do any of this additional work before, i just deployed and it worked.

Comment: @Spongman The certificate resolution logic was introduced in .NET Core 2.1 and remains the same in later releases, so either you were deploying a very old version of .NET Core "before", or something has already changed on this machine (for example, someone deleted a preconfigured certificate). Personally I prefer to link to a certificate explicitly, and don't rely on the default resolution mechanism. That's why I wrote the answer above.

Comment: How to disabled HTTPS in this case? When behind a proxy that does SSL termination

Comment: @DouglasGaskell You don't need to do anything if hosting on IIS, so I assume you are asking about Linux? The latest guide like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=linux-ubuntu#publish-and-copy-over-the-app does indicate how to remove HTTPS and the redirection, which you can take a look.